# Notification app like Slack for single person

Tags: web-apps, notification, hosted

I'd like to send notifications like you can to Slack channels but just for myself.

Is there an online service that can gather all these messages or alerts besides using email? Ideally something that's been out there a while with good support and mobile app.

Comment: What about using the calendar for this purpose?

Comment: Why not just use slack?

Comment: cause it's a little overkill for my needs

Comment: How about [PushBullet](https://www.pushbullet.com/)?